# Blank (X' out) middle numbers letters

Tags: php

Is there a way to blank / x' out the middle (keep first and last two) digits / letters of a word or number ?

Example:

123456789 would be 12XXXXX89  or Iamaword = Iaxxxxrd

Comment: Have you had a look at the [built-in string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)?

Comment: This is basic string manipulation. Read the manual before you read the answer here, so that you understand the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't sure if the uppercase or lowercase Xs were necessary, so the first line could be removed for simplicity:

```
$chr = ctype_digit($str) ? 'X' : 'x';  // big X for numbers, x for letters

$new_str = substr($str, 0, 2) . str_repeat($chr, strlen($str) - 4) . substr($str, -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
<?php

    function secure_str($str) {
        return substr($str, 0, 2) . str_repeat('X', strlen($str)-4) . substr($str, strlen($str)-2);
    }

    echo secure_str("1234567890");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function blankit($word) {
    return substr($word, 0,2). str_repeat("X",strlen($word)-4) . substr($word, strlen($word)-2,strlen($word));
} 

echo blankit("abcdefghijklmn");
```

prints

```
abXXXXXXXXXXmn
```